# Verifying bigquery successful upload via command prompt/scheduled task

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks, command-line-tool

I'm trying to run a file upload in to BigQuery via a scheduled task (.bat file), the code below works fine for doing this (picking up any csv and using the schema which populates a table with the same name and then moving the original file).

What I would like to do within this is, should the load fail to not move the file - Any help or am I trying to do something too complicated for a simple command line execution?

```
@ECHO Off
for %%g in (c:\Test\*.csv) do (
    bq load --source_format=CSV my_project:data.%%~ng %%g c:\Test\schema.txt
    move %%g c:\Test\archive\%%~ng.csv
)
```

Note: It is validating my credentials okay prior to running this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a best practice, you can manually create the Job ID for a load job.So once bigquery starts the job you can poll the job status periodically to check the status whether it is SUCCESS/FAILURE/RUNNING,then you can choose to move the csv file to archive folder based on this status.

Here are some documentation links around this

[Generate Job ID programmatically](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-jobs#generate-jobid)

[Viewing Job Status](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs)